# Sync .sqlite file through iCloud

Tags: sqlite, core-data, icloud, encrypted-core-data-sql

My app Coredata which use **NSPersistentContainer** save the .sqlite file in App.
Now I would like to save the .sqlite file in iCloud  **UbiquityContainer** in order many device can access the same database and it works, but I am not sure that if the file will corrupt in future, so I would like to ask if someone has experience?
I dont want to use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer because its to slow to sync and I tried that user must be at least 40 seconds in foreground to sync it with iCloud.
I believe moving .sqlite file in iCloud can be good solution but I am not sure about the performance that can corrupt.

Comment: Sqlite is not a multiuser database server.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what kind of database you suggest me?

Comment: I am not suggesting anything, it all depends on your needs. Firebase seems to be a popular option, maybe check it out.